# Выполняется только первая голосовая команда

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, pyttsx3

В данный момент я, с помощью библиотек `SpeechRecognition` `pyttsx3` пытаюсь создать голосового ассистента, который будет выполнять некоторые команды (в данный момент их три) но несмотря на простоту кода, он почему-то работает неправильно.
Вот код...

```
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import pyttsx3

def openFile_orProgram(dir):
    try:
        os.startfile(dir)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

def closeFile_orProgram(name_of_program):
    try:
        os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM " + name_of_program)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

def talk(word):
    print("[log]Jarvis - " + word)
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(word)
    engine.runAndWait()

def recognize_cmd():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

    with m as source:
        print("---------")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        cmd = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-EN').lower()
        print("[log]User - " + cmd + '\n---------')
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        talk("Voice is not recognized!")
        cmd = recognize_cmd()

    return cmd

def execute_cmd(cmd):
    if 'open google' or 'open chrome' or 'open google chrome' in cmd:
        openFile_orProgram('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk')

    elif 'close google' or 'close chrome' or 'close google chrome' in cmd:
        closeFile_orProgram('chrome.exe')

    elif 'stop' in cmd:
        talk("Good bye...")
        sys.exit()

talk('Good day my Master')
print('---------')
talk('Jarvis is listening and ready to do everything')

while True:
    execute_cmd(recognize_cmd())
```

В функции execute_cmd() пока что есть только три команды, и в любом случаи выполняется только первый
Я это выяснил меняя череду `if`-ов в коде функции и каждый раз при любой команде, даже не существующей, выполнялась только первая команда.

Помогите исправить, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не верно пишите условия в execute_cmd, нужно так:

```
def execute_cmd(cmd):
    if 'open google' in cmd or 'open chrome' in cmd or 'open google chrome' in cmd:
        openFile_orProgram('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk')

    elif 'close google' in cmd or 'close chrome' in cmd or 'close google chrome' in cmd:
        closeFile_orProgram('chrome.exe')

    elif 'stop' in cmd:
        talk("Good bye...")
        sys.exit()
```

p.s. вариант приведенный в вашем коде будет всегда возвращать первую строку из условия, например 'open google', которая в операторе if будет воспринята как True и соответственно всегда выполняется только первое условие

Или же ещё один способ реализации, чтобы не писать условие на каждую команду:

```
cmd = 'open google'
OPEN_GOOGLE_COMMANDS = ['open google', 'open chrome', 'open google chrome']

if any([(command in cmd) for command in OPEN_GOOGLE_COMMANDS]):
    # open google chrome
    pass
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать намного проще.

```
def execute_cmd(cmd):
    if cmd in ['open chrome','open chrome','open google chrome':
       openFile_orProgram('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk')

    elif cmd in ['close google','close chrome','close google chrome']:
        closeFile_orProgram('chrome.exe')

    elif cmd in ['stop','good bye']:
        talk("Good bye...")
        sys.exit()
```

Таким образом вы ищите cmd в списке команд это удобнее

Comment: это решение вносит и ограничение, а что если пользователь скажет ещё какое-то слово а потом команду?) cmd = 'please close google'

Comment: Тогда можно сделать цикл 'for' и каждое его значение проверять в cmd

Comment: Просто в PEP-8 да и в дзене сказано что нежелательно делать длинные строки кода, потому и даю вам такой вариант

Comment: Если интересно, посмотрите вариант выше) Постарался внедрить ту же логику с минимальной длинной строк)

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk, все, увидел